# Question About Momentum $p=mv$?

Tags: classical-mechanics, momentum, definition

How Can We Derive the [Momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum) $p=mv$ Equation. Is there Any Mathematical Proof To Solve this Equation Directly. Or we can Said Momentum(p)=Mass(m)×Velocity(v)?

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking.  What is a "Mathematical Proof To Solve this Equation Directly"?  I don't understand what "solve" means for this.

Answer (score 1):

The term $mv$ appears here and there and has turned out to be useful. When something turns out to be useful, people will eventually give it a name, for example **momentum**, and a symbol, for example $p$.

That is really all there is to it. It is not a "proved" quantity, which doesn't really make sense since this is not an equation. It is merely a *definition*.